# Any better way for handling a div insie a div anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I am looking for a better solution for handling an entire div inside a Anchor tag ....

I am listing users insie a loop ..... If I click a user's block I need to redirect to that person's page.... Is there any better solutions for that....

I need to use the anchor tag for the user first and it should work the link on the whole block.

Here is my code

```
<ul class="no-padding">
    {% for user in users %}
         <a href="{% url 'user-profile' pk=user.pk %}">
            <li class="item padding-15 teams">
                <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d64 circular">
                    <img data-src-retina="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}" data-src="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}" src="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}">
                </div>
                <div class="inline m-l-15">
                    <p class="recipients no-margin hint-text small">{{user.first_name}}</p>
                    <p class="subject no-margin">{{ user.designation }}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
      </a>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Team lead ask me for a better approach

I need to use the anchor tag for the user first name and it should work the link on the whole block.

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: What does "work the link on the whole block" mean?

Comment: Maybe you just want `<a href="{% url 'user-profile' pk=user.pk %}">{{user.first_name}}</a>`?

Comment: I am listing user first name, profile static image and designation 

I need to user anchor tag for user first name . Normally it works if I click on the first name right 

But if I clcik anywhere in the list it needs to work

Comment: Add a `click` event listener on the `<ul>` that redirects to the URL in the anchor tag.

Comment: You mean 
<ul class ="teams">

Comment: $(".teams").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return false;
});

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

- keep the anchor for user's first name only and you can add a click event listener
  for the div or li part.
- pass the url info you're using to the function and redirect using javascript

Hope this helps

```js
redirect(url) {
  location.replace(url);
}
```

```html
<ul class="no-padding">
    {% for user in users %}
         <a href="{% url 'user-profile' pk=user.pk %}">
          {{user.first_name}}
         </a>
            <li class="item padding-15 teams" onClick="redirect({% url 'user-profile' pk=user.pk %})">
                <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d64 circular">
                    <img data-src-retina="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}" data-src="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}" src="{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}">
                </div>
                <div class="inline m-l-15">
                    <p class="recipients no-margin hint-text small">{{user.first_name}}</p>
                    <p class="subject no-margin">{{ user.designation }}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: It show's (index):747 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags